# mysql describe table - concatenate fields?

Tags: mysql, group-concat, describe

Is there a way to use GROUP_CONCAT in the DESCRIBE table query?  Was hoping for output like:

id,title,body

Rather than the typical description...

Comment: Do you want to get tables definitions at once? You could make a dump of all tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE
    TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() 
AND TABLE_NAME='your-table-name';
```